# With Makie, how to incrementally add stacked bars to plot?

Tags: plot, julia, makie.jl

With the following code, the bars overlap. **How to get the bars to stack on top of each other?**

```
using CairoMakie
x = 1:10

b = barplot(x,rand(10))
barplot!(x,rand(10))
b
```

The result of the above code:
[image: A bar plot with overlapping bars instead of stacked bars]

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following based on [discourse.julialang](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/current-advice-on-stacked-bar-plots-with-makie/57095).

```
rnd1 = rand(10)
rnd2 = rand(10)
x = 1:10

fig = Figure();
ax = Axis(fig[1,1]);
barplot!(ax, x, rnd1 .+ rnd2, color=:blue)
barplot!(ax, x, rnd1, color=:orange)
fig
```

[image]

It is a workaround that simply adds both random values together in the first barplot, and puts the second on top.

`stack` does not work with rand directly (Makie [restricts](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/AbstractPlotting.jl/pull/580#issuecomment-823204424) inputs of `stack` and `dodge` to integers) but for integers you can use the following code snippet from the [documentation](https://docs.makie.org/stable/examples/plotting_functions/barplot/index.html#barplot):

```
tbl = (x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       height = 0.1:0.1:0.9,
       grp = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
       )

barplot(tbl.x, tbl.height,
        stack = tbl.grp,
        color = tbl.grp,
        axis = (xticks = (1:3, ["left", "middle", "right"]),
                title = "Stacked bars"),
        )
```

Of course, if it does not have to be Makie, you can also use something like:

```
using DataFrames, StatsPlots
groupedbar(hcat(rnd1, rnd2), bar_position=:stack)
```

[image]